# Tableau Dashboard without password in Tableau Online

Tags: tableau-api

I have Tableau Online. I have a few dashboards that I want to share without password access and embed in my public website. When I embed it ask for the password. I have tried various tableau authentication but its only available in Tableau Server.

Comment: Is it asking for a database password or for a Tableau Online user password?

Comment: @SamM Database connection is already embedded. When I open a link or embed in a web browser then it asks for Tableau Online Username and Password.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are attempting to do is not possible. Guest access, which is what you are describing, is only available with Tableau Server. Tableau Online has a different licensing model and does not include guest access. An alternative you might consider is to publish your data to Tableau Public. Tableau Public requires no authentication.

This limitation is documented in the Tableau help files as well as a number of Tableau community forum posts on their website.

Answer (score 1):

You could try publishing it somewhere and embedding your password. They give you that option in Tableau desktop.

Answer (score 0):

Guest access is not supported in tableau online. As it is only supported in Tableau Desktop.

Answer (score 0):

Tableau Public offers a free way to share online. But would have to remove any confidential/non secure data as it essentially becomes open source on the tableau server.